# Time out error while executing the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

I am executing the following query in a stored procedure, transferring one year's transactions from one table to another:

```
insert into 
    table2 
select
    * 
from 
    table1 
where 
    dates between '20110101' and 20111231'
```

When I use VB6 to call the stored procedure, it times out.

I've tried to set the `QueryTimeout` property on my RDO Connection to five seconds like so:

```
RdoConn.QueryTimeout = 5000
```

But it's still timing out.

How can I prevent the execution of the query from timing out?

Comment: Your query lasts more than 5 seconds, try to make timeout = 0 - it disables it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an Ado connection you can use the following code

```
dim myConn 
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
myConn.CommandTimeout = 3600
myConn.ConnectionTimeout = 3600
```

and then use this connection to execute your query.

**How much time does your query take to run without issue?**

Update:
Using RdoConnection, you can try to set event the LoginTimeout

```
RdoConn.QueryTimeout = 5000
RdoConn.LoginTimeout = 5000
```

or as pointed out by [Oleg Dok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076216/time-out-error-while-executing-the-query#comment11451512_9076216)

```
RdoConn.QueryTimeout = 0 'disable timeout
RdoConn.LoginTimeout = 0 'disable timeout
```

Comment: not executing single row, it was taking 30 minutes and showing time out error, and i'm using rdo connection

Comment: 30 minutes??? You'll get a HUGE advantage by 1) using a real date column and 2) adding an index.

Answer (score 1):

Your two options (without changing the database schema) are:

1) Increase your timeout time eg:

```
RdoConn.QueryTimeout = 30000
```

2) If your query is taking longer than 30 seconds to execute then you should probably try breaking down your select statement into smaller parts:

```
Insert into table2 select * from table1 where dates between '20110101' and 20110131'
Insert into table2 select * from table1 where dates between '20110201' and 20110228'
```

As mentioned though you should also look at indexes and data types in your database to improve performance